# Move minicart widgets to the top

Tags: magento2

Is it possible to move the minicart widgets to the top of the minicart?

When I add CMS blocks now they are added to the bottom, but I would want to move this widget to the beginning of `minicart-content-wrapper`

See screenshot:
[image]

Comment: could you please share code how you added widget (container you used) ?

Comment: I didn't add one, I said I wanted to move the one at the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

Firstly, copy minicart.phtml from the below path

> vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/cart/minicart.phtml

To

> app/design/frontend/vendor/theme-name/Magento_Checkout/templates/cart/minicart.phtml

then add the below code

```
<div id="minicart-content-wrapper" data-bind="scope: 'minicart_content'">    // After this div tag and line number : 40 add the below code in it
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('cms_block_identifier')->toHtml(); ?>
```

Hope this helps :)